# Spring Boot | Multiple dispatcher Servlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm starting with a new Spring Boot application and I need to have two Dispatcher servlets. I'm doing something like this:

```
public class ApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);

        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.register(DispatcherConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic uiDispatcher = container.addServlet("uiDispatcher",
                new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        uiDispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        uiDispatcher.setInitParameter("initializeJ2EE", "false");
        uiDispatcher.addMapping("/ui/*");

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic utilDispatcher = container.addServlet("utilDispatcher",
                new DispatcherServlet());
        utilDispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        utilDispatcher.setInitParameter("initializeJ2EE", "false");
        utilDispatcher.addMapping("/util/*");

        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
    }
```

Does this look at the right thing to do? In past I've never had to use 'WebApplicationInitializer ' for Boot applications. WOuld this be required in case I need multiple Dispatcher servlets or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: No it doesn't. Also do you **really** need 2 dispatcher servlets what is your use case? That being said you can just define 2 `DispatcherServlet` beans in your `@SpringBootApplication` manage them with a `ServletRegistrationBean` to have them added as a servlet. What you are doing is actually going to break all of the Spring Boot things you are used to be using.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It does. Spring provides us `web.xml` and `WebApplicationInitializer` to configure a DispatcherServlet (even hybrid both of them).
If you interest on `web.xml` for multiple `DispathcherServlet`. This is an example

```
<servlet>
    <description>Monitor</description>
    <servlet-name>monitor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>monitor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/monitor</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <description>Metrics</description>
    <servlet-name>metrics</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>metrics</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/metrics/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't, not for a Spring Boot application.